# @JsonIgnoreProperties doesn't work in @OneToMany relation

Tags: java

@JsonIgnoreProperties doesn't work properly

I'm writing a one to many relation, one property can have multiply propertySale, I try to use @JsonIgnoreProperties to avoid infinite recursion, but for some reason it doesn't work when I try to save a propertySale. Counld someone please tell me where I do wrong?

In Property.java

```
@Data
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "Property")
public class Property {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="property", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = PropertySale.class)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("property")
    private Set<PropertySale> propertySales = new HashSet<>();
    ...
    public void addPropertySale(PropertySale propertySale){
        this.propertySales.add(propertySale);
    }

}
```

In PropertySale.java

```
@Data
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "PropertySale")
public class PropertySale {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "property_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("propertySales")
    private Property property;
    ...
```

In PropertySaleServiceImp.java

```
@Service
public class PropertySaleServiceImp implements PropertySaleService{

    @Autowired
    private PropertySaleRepository propertySaleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private PropertyRepository propertyRepository;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<PropertySale> savePropertySale(PropertySale propertySale) {
        Optional<Property> existPropertyOpt = this.propertyRepository.findById(propertySale.getProperty().getId());

        if(existPropertyOpt.isPresent()){
            Example<PropertySale> propertySaleExample =  Example.of(propertySale);
            Optional<PropertySale> existPropSale = this.propertySaleRepository.findOne(propertySaleExample);
            if(existPropSale.isPresent()){
                throw new PropertySaleAlreadyExistException();

            }else{
                Property existProperty = existPropertyOpt.get();
                propertySale.setProperty(existProperty);
                existProperty.addPropertySale(propertySale);
                this.propertyRepository.save(existProperty);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(propertySale, HttpStatus.CREATED);
            }

        }else{
            throw new PropertyNotFoundException(propertySale.getProperty().getId());
        }
    }
```

I get 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
when the line `this.propertyRepository.save(existProperty);`
is executed.

Comment: JsonIgnoreProperties annotation is wrong. Remove @JsonIgnoreProperties from Property class and set @JsonIgnoreProperties("property") on  PropertySale entity at Property attribute.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I get 'java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed' after doing what you say, do you know why does that happen? Thank you.